# import/no-duplicates eslint rule with different file extensions

Tags: javascript, eslint

I'm trying to enable [import/no-duplicates](https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/blob/HEAD/docs/rules/no-duplicates.md) eslint rule in my project, but there is a problem. I get an error in the following code:

```js
import foo from 'foo.json'
import { Bar } from 'foo'
```

These are obviously two different files, but I get an error. And --fix actually breaks my app, producing this invalid code:

```js
import foo, { Bar } from 'foo'
```

How do i configure eslint not to treat imports with different file extensions as duplicates?

Comment: The docs that you link to say this quite early on: "ESLint core has a similar rule (no-duplicate-imports), but this version is different in two key ways:", and then lists them, of which 1) is exactly the thing you want to disable, and 2) is something about Flow types. So unless the Flow thing is critical to you (perhaps it is, but you don't say - if I was sure it wasn't, this would be an answer), can't you just use `no-duplicate imports` instead of this rule?